# ActiveRecord::SubclassNotFound in UsersController#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm newbie Ruby, i had some error when i make authentication from Scratch, this is my error
"The single-table inheritance mechanism failed to locate the subclass: 'true'. This error is raised because the column 'type' is reserved for storing the class in case of inheritance. Please rename this column if you didn't intend it to be used for storing the inheritance class or overwrite User.inheritance_column to use another column for that information."

My user.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController   
  def new       
    @user = User.new   
  end
  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      flash[:notice] = "You signed up successfully"
      flash[:color]= "valid"
    else
      flash[:notice] = "Form is invalid"
      flash[:color]= "invalid"
    end
    render "new"   end

private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name_company, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)   end    
end
```

My model/user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  attr_accessor :password
  before_save :encrypt_password

  validates_confirmation_of :password
  validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create
  validates_presence_of :email
  validates_uniqueness_of :email

  def self.authenticate(email, password)
    user = find_by_email(email)
    if user && user.password_hash == BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, user.password_salt)
      user
    else
      nil
    end
  end

  def encrypt_password
    if password.present?
      self.password_salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
      self.password_hash = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, password_salt)
    end
  end
end
```

Anyone can help me. Thank you.

Comment: Can you post the migration for the user model?

Comment: Your User model probably has a column called 'type'.  You should read up on the rails schema conventions(http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html).  Specifically you might want to read up on Single Table Inheritance and since I'm pretty sure that's not what you want to do; try setting self.inheritance_column = nil in your User model.  The error message for this one really does provide enough that you should be able to get pretty far by googling parts of it.